# ',' or ')' expected

Tags: java

Может, я что-то не вижу, но как понимаю, нигде не упустил ";" и ")". Подсвечивается после первого и второго LocalDate.

```
public List<Contract> findAllByDate(LocalDate startDate, LocalDate endDate) {
        return contractRepository.findAllByDate(LocalDate startDate, LocalDate endDate);
    }
```

А вот метод, который вызываем, он не подсвечивается:

```
@Query(value = "select * from contract WHERE visit_date > :startDate and visit_date < cast(:endDay as date) + interval '1' day", nativeQuery = true)
    List<Contract> findAllByDate(@Param("startDay") LocalDate startDate, @Param("endDay") LocalDate endDay);}
```

Comment: Может лучше `return contractRepository.findAllByDate(startDate, endDate)`?

Comment: @mrEvgenX определённо лучше) Да, вот, что упустил) Напишите ответ, что не нужно тип параметра пихать, может, пригодится кому

Comment: а с вас принять его как правильный, будет понятный для всех сигнал и мне приятно)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Типы данных нужны только в объявлении, при вызове это лишнее.

`return contractRepository.findAllByDate(startDate, endDate)`